# How to handle relationships from separate EF Core schemas/contexts?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I am working on a brand new app and decided to try DDD for the first time, so bear with me on that front but please correct me where I am wrong on my understanding of how to implement.  I have watched a great deal of Pluralsight videos on the subject now, but they don't deal with these more advanced use cases so not sure where to go.   Have tried several things and I am stuck on what to do.   One of those first things you hit after the tutorial deals.   :)

I have a fairly complicated domain but I will only show the simple example part that matters for this question.  I have 2 schemas...identity and network.  In those schemas, I have 2 tables.  In Identity, I have a normal aspnet_users table (user from now on) for users in the system.   In the Network schema, I have an aggregate root called Network.   The network is the heart of a large part of my domain and is just a collection of items for sake of a long explanation.  In a network, I can have 0, 1, or many items...such as an 'event'.  When a user creates an event within the network, I need to be able to capture the user that created the event.  Not a hard biz requirement, or a db requirement...stick a created_by_user_id field on the Network table and call it good.

This is where my issues start though.  While this isn't a big deal when the user is in the same bounded context, my user table is in the IdentityDbContext and the Event table is in the NetworkDbContext.

I have attached relevant classes for points below...if you think something is missing that you need, please ask and I will provide.  I didn't add the stuff around users since it is truly just the microsoft aspnet users table implementation.

Here you can see, the network domain entity contains "Name" which is a Value Object that wraps up the Name of the network.   This all works fine.    The CreateByUserId without the navigation property doing the non-DDD way works fine.   When I started making it DDD friendly, I wanted to remove the CreatedByUserId field and only have the CreatedByUser.   The issue is that the User that this points to is in the Identity context, not the network context.

DOMAIN CLASS - NETWORK

```
public class Network : IntegerEntity
    {
        public NetworkName Name { get;  set; }

        public int CreatedByUserId { get; private set; }
        public User CreatedByUser { get; private set; }


        private Network() { }

        public Network(NetworkName name, User createdByUser)
        {
            Name = name;
            CreatedByUser = createdByUser;
        }

        public Network(int id, NetworkName name, User createdByUser) : base(id)
        {
            Name = name;
            CreatedByUser = createdByUser;
        }
    }
```

Here in the type configuration, you can see I have a couple things that need to be pointed out:

1. I am using EF Type Configuration with migrations.  I have attached the type config for my network root/table (NetworkTypeConfig).  The NetworkBaseTypeConfiguration base class just points that table to the "network" schema so each table's code didn't have to specify it.   But that Base class also derives from a class called BaseTypeConfiguration.   That class orchestrates the creation of the table for the type config....basically allows you to override which functions you need...you see that network is configuring columns, relationships, and ignored relationships currently, but the 2 latter ones aren't actually doing anything right now.
2. We are using Postgres....which is not case friendly so we elected to lowercase all table and fields so we don't have to write queries with quotes.   This is the .HasColumnName stuff...all works fine, but I do need it to work on all tables/columns/nav props.

TYPE CONFIGURATION - NETWORK

```
 public class NetworkTypeConfiguration : NetworkBaseTypeConfiguration<Network, int>
    {
        public NetworkTypeConfiguration() : base(TableEnums.CoreTables.Networks.GetName()) { }


        public override void ConfigureColumns()
        {
            base.ConfigureColumns();

            Builder.Property(x => x.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName(NetworksEnums.NetworksColumns.Name.GetName())
                .HasConversion(x => x.Name, y => NetworkName.Create(y).Value);

            Builder.Property(x => x.CreatedByUserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName(NetworksEnums.NetworksColumns.Created_By_User_Id.GetName());
        }

        public override void ConfigureRelationships()
        {
            //Builder.HasOne(x => x.CreatedByUser)
            //    .WithMany()
            //    .HasForeignKey(x => x.CreatedByUserId)
            //    .IsRequired();

            //Builder.HasOne<User>()
            //    .WithMany()
            //    .HasForeignKey(x => x.CreatedByUserId)
            //    .IsRequired();
        }

        public override void ConfigureIgnoredRelationships()
        {
            //Builder.Ignore(x => x.CreatedByUser);
            //Builder.Ignore(x => x.CreatedByUserId);
            
        }
    }
```

TYPE CONFIGURATION - BASE TYPE

```
public abstract class BaseTypeConfiguration<TEntity, TKey> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>
        {
            private const string _COLUMN_ID = "id";
    
            private readonly string _schemaName;
            private readonly string _tableName;
    
            public EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> Builder { get; internal set; }
    
            public BaseTypeConfiguration(string schemaName, string tableName)
            {
                _schemaName = schemaName;
                _tableName = tableName;
            }
    
            public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
            {
                Builder = builder;
    
                ConfigureSchema();
                ConfigureTable();
                ConfigureColumns();
                ConfigureRelationships();
                ConfigureIgnoredRelationships();
            }
    
            public virtual void ConfigureSchema()
            {
                Builder.Metadata.SetSchema(_schemaName);
            }
    
            public virtual void ConfigureTable()
            {
                Builder.ToTable(_tableName);
            }
            
            public virtual void ConfigureColumns()
            {
                Builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    
                Builder.Property(x => x.Id)
                    .HasColumnName(_COLUMN_ID);
            }
    
            public virtual void ConfigureRelationships() { }
            public virtual void ConfigureIgnoredRelationships() { }
        }
```

Now for the real issue(s)...these are what I have tried...

1. With the type config like it is...only referencing the Id field, I had this working from an EF standpoint as far as I could tell.  But I didn't have the encapsulation that DDD is supposed to provide my model.  I was managing everything in a NetworkService class instead of inside the Network entity.
2. If I remove the created_by_user_id column completely and use pure DDD guidance (at least guidance is what I can gather), I run into the issue that the CreatedByUser property can't be filled out by the EF context...makes sense...the Network context doesn't understand "user".   I know I can support this via stored proc, but I don't what to go that route as I would prefer it to be in code.  I can also look the user up after and add to the ViewModel that is being returned, but that sucks to have to make 2 db calls.
3. If I leave the created by user id column, but I add the .HasOne on CreatedByUser, then when I run the migrations code, EF creates the User/etc tables in the context.   Not sure if this even works to solve the issue, since it tries to create the user's tables on migration which is duplicate of what the identity context does so my migrations fail.

What am I supposed to do here?   I have a hard biz requirement that I have to keep track of who created the event and that logically is the aspnet_user record.

I have read about things like Event sourcing models and such to pushes changes around in the system...like when a user is created in the Identity Domain fire an event and then create an appropriate entry in the network context...ie...separate table for network users.   Do I have to do this to support DDD?   Basically every table I want to have CreatedBy/UdpatedBy users on as we track all this data.
Seems like a lot of extra work to support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a direct way to accomplish what I needed to do here, but I was able to come up with a workable solution.   It wasn't an ideal solution, but it works.

I effectively used the concept from "issue #3" above.   I created a new DbContext for EF that is solely responsible for the schema migrations.  This EF context contains a DbSet for every table in the database and will be used only during the database migration.   Each schema specific context is still used for database transactions in the system.

The reason this works is because the migration context now understands all the tables in the entire database and will not duplicate the "fringe" tables that sit on the border between the bounded contexts....ie...user in this case.   The only real drawback I see here is the duplication of code to manage the same tables in 2 contexts.   This still seems like a lot less work than creating slimmed down "user" tables in every context I create just so I can link to who the person was that created a row.